# Spring JPA: Dual Datasource - Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring JPA, dual data source in my application. Both Datasources works just fine. But intermittently (usually when application is idle / when difference between access time for 1st data source is 1 minute), it throw below exception when a new request comes in

For example, I made a write on master db -> Access slave db for some read operation for more than 1 minute -> Access master to write again, here below error is thrown

> Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed

Attaching master and slave database configuration as below.

Master Database Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myproject.master.dao",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager")
public class MasterDatabaseConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(masterDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.myproject.master.dao" });

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect",
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

    properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto",
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));

    properties.put("spring.jmx.default-domain", env.getProperty("spring.jmx.default-domain"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit"));

    properties.put("spring.jpa.open-in-view", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.open-in-view"));
    properties.put("spring.jpa.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));

    properties.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy",
        SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
    properties.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy",
        SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());

    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource masterDataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public PlatformTransactionManager masterTransactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(masterEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

}
```

Slave Database Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.myproject.salve.services",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "slaveEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "slaveTransactionManager")
public class SlaveDatabaseConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean slaveEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(slaveDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.myproject.salve.services" });

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect",
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect"));

    properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto",
        env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));

    properties.put("spring.jmx.default-domain", env.getProperty("spring.jmx.default-domain"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle"));

    properties.put("spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit",
        env.getProperty("spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit"));

    properties.put("spring.jpa.open-in-view", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.open-in-view"));
    properties.put("spring.jpa.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));

    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource slaveDataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("spring.replica.ds.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("spring.replica.ds.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("spring.replica.ds.password"));

    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager slaveTransactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(slaveEntityManager().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing this issue too

Answer (score 0):

You may use datasource validation for avoiding such errors. You should change the validation query according to your database.

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout for the database is 8 hours. It may restart after 8 hours of inactivity.

You can configure tomcat connection pool as follows :

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=select 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.log-abandoned=true

# Maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time.
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=30
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-age=18000000

#Validate the connection before borrowing it from the pool.
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.num-tests-per-eviction-run=3
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.remove-abandoned-timeout=82800
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=600000
```